ImportError: cannot import name 'DataError' from 'pandas.core.base'
Getting the following error while running pandas profiling. Why this has popped up? how to resolve?

ImportError: cannot import name 'DataError' from 'pandas.core.base' (C:\Users\subrat\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py)


Please include a [mre] with the imports you are performing, and the full error traceback for that MRE.

Can you share which version of pandas and pandas-profiling you are using.
May be its some version compatibility issue.
Also share your Python version.

Pandas version: 2.2.2
Python - 3.11.7 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc.
